# Remove row below the row with gif image on every ajax call in c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

Unfortunately, it added rows to the table on every ajax call:

If I remove below code it works fine for multiple open/collapse functionality

```
if ($('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr tr').length <= 1)
```

Length remains 1 once ,on 2nd call the length comes greater then 1 and so it does not goes inside **if condition**

```
<tr>
    <td id="lding<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>" style="display: none;">
        <p>Loading....</p>
        <img id="imgld" src="../img/loading.gif" alt="loading.." height="75px;" width="100px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

With table referred as

```
 $('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr')
```

But with the below code ,it goes on adding the rows on every ajax call to my table name

```
 $('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr tr')
```

Here is my Js code:

```
 function DisplayPrdWeightGrd(index, OrderId, isAdmin) {
        $('#lding' + index).show();
        var Admin = isAdmin.toLowerCase();
        if ($('#img_' + index).attr("class") == "splashy-arrow_state_grey_expanded") {
            $('#img_' + index).attr("class", "splashy-arrow_state_grey_left");
        } else {
            $('#img_' + index).attr("class", "splashy-arrow_state_grey_expanded");

            var Orderid = OrderId;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../handlers/DisplayOrderDetail.ashx?OrderId=" + Orderid + "&tk=" + $.now(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {


                    if ($('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr tr').length <= 1) {
                        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
                            setDataOnRow(index, v, i);
                        });
                    }        
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    alert("fail");
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }    
        function setDataOnRow(idx, v, i) {
            $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr:last').after('<tr>' +
                '<td width="25%" >' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
                '<td width="25%" class="center">' + v.ProductName + '</td>' +
                '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.NoOfCarton + '</td>' +
                '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.ProductQuantity + '</td>' +
                '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.OriginalPrice + '</td>' +
                '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.OrderPrice + '</td>' +
                '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.Discount + '</td>' +
                '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.TotalPrice + '</td></tr>');
            $('#lding' + index).hide();
        }

        $('#trPwd_' + index).toggle("slow");
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_us" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_us_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rpt_us_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dTableR">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="7%">Detail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="center" style="cursor: pointer">
                <span onclick="DisplayPrdWeightGrd('<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>','<%# Eval(" OrderId ")%>','<%= Convert.ToBoolean(Utility.IsAdmin()) %>');">
                         <img id="img_<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>" class="splashy-arrow_state_grey_left" />
                     </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none" id="trPwd_<%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>">
            <td colspan="10" style="horizontal-align: center; padding-bottom: 15px">
                <div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 3px"> <b>Order Details </b></div>
                <table id="tableOrderDetail_<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>" class="table-striped table-bordered" style="align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%">Sr. No. </th>
                            <th width="35%">Product Name </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="lding<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>" style="display: none;">
                                <p>Loading....</p>
                                <img id="imgld" src="../img/loading.gif" alt="loading.." height="75px;" width="100px;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I tried debugger & check the condition

```
 if ($('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr tr').length <= 1)
```

whose length remains 0 each time and so every time it goes inside if condition and generates the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have two rows in your table and that's why your if condition will not work properly.

You have to change:

```
$('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr tr')
```

To this way.

```
if ($('#tableOrderDetail_' + index).children().children().length <= 2) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    setDataOnRow(index, v, i);
                  });                        
      }
```

Hope this helps!